# How to change statusBarStyle programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift

I am building an app for iOS13. I want to change the text color of status bar according to the color scheme which user can select. It seems the text color of status bar cannot be changed directly, so I try to change the statusBarStyle instead.

First I try:

```
var myStatusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.default { didSet { setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate() } }
override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle { return myStatusBarStyle; }
```

But it did not work.

Then I try:

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = myStatusBarStyle;
```

It does do the job! But Xcode gives a warnning: " 'statusBarStyle' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Use the statusBarManager property of the window scene insted."

so, in sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) I try:

```
guard let ws = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
if let t = ws.statusBarManager { print(t.statusBarStyle) }
```

Unfortunately, t.statusBarStyle is readonly.

Now, how can I do?
ps: I have no Navigation Bar or Tab Bar in the Main.storyboard.

Comment: Is the view controller in which you've overridden `preferredStatusBarStyle` a child view controller of another view controller in any way? If so then you need to override `preferredStatusBarStyle` in the _parent_ view controller (or rather, the one at the "root" – the one with no parent).

Comment: I just have only one ViewController. (And I can change the background color of status bar with a statement:  self.view.backgroundColor=myColor; )

Comment: In your info.plist, do you have `View controller-based status bar appearance` set to `YES`?

Comment: Yes, I have set it as YES.

Answer (score 2):

- in iOS 13, we are not allowed to do that but there are always escape roots..
  I used

```
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
```

To make status bar black and it works

You can use various options instead of black as you like (.default , .blackTranslucent , .blackOpaque) in place of .black

Comment: The question is about the _status bar_'s text color, not a _navigation bar_'s text color.

Comment: yes, thank you ...my second point was invalid but `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black` makes status bar black and make status bar text white and works vice versa with `.default`

Comment: The question asker says they are not using a navigation controller. Furthermore, what if they don't want a navigation controller? Or if they do, what if they don't want to change the color of the navigation bar's background? The correct thing to do is to override `preferredStatusBarStyle` in the most parent view controller and call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` on it.

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler, what if I want to change the color of text of the status bar according to the selection of user? Black or white, it's not fixed.